# How do I turn down a project I'm not interested in anymore?

Tags: research-undergraduate, rejection

I'm an undergraduate student, and I recently got in touch with a postdoc at an institution different from mine - since I was quite interested in her research work. Now, after a few weeks (haven't started much work yet, I've only gone through the preliminaries I'd need to do research in that field), I don't feel as interested in the project/work, and I wonder what would be a polite way to say the same. Since I haven't been offered an official position at the lab yet, I think this is still a good time to make this call.

As an undergraduate in my early years, I think I'm still figuring out my interests, so I'm personally not as surprised at my situation - but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to inform the postdoc that I'm not interested in that particular project anymore. I hope y'all understand my situation and can help!

**I'm confused because I was the one who reached out first, expressed interest and I'm not interested anymore. I hope there's an easy way out of this.**

Comment: "Hey George, I looked up my schedule and I think I won't have time this semester." ?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A polite and concise email to the postdoc will suffice.

> As an undergraduate in my early years, I think I'm still figuring out my interests

A postdoc researcher will certainly understand this sentiment. There is no need to go into details about you not finding their work interesting, but rather focus on changes in your interests.

> Since I haven't been offered an official position at the lab yet, I think this is still a good time to make this call.

The postdoc will be glad that you did not waste their time and they will appreciate knowing about your decision to not join their lab ahead of time.